# I can't figure out how to set up CRON job for range time in one line

Tags: cron, cron-task

I can't figure out how to set up CRON job for range time in one line.

Example 1) : Every 5 min from 00:30 to 01:00 on the workdays

Expecting Cron job : 30,35,40,45,50,55 0 * * 1-5 but missing at 1:00

If config 0,30,35,40,45,50,55 0,1 * * 1-5

==> the issue is it will run 00:00,1:00,1:30,1:35,1:35,1:40,1:45,1:50,1:55 which are out of our scope.

Example 2) : Every 10 min from 01:00 to 04:30 on the workdays

Expecting Cron job : 0,10,20,30,40,50, 1-4 * * 1-5

The out of scope is a running at 4:40,:4:50

Could someone please help this query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can write single line configs for these ranges because cron runs at every minute specified for every hour as you've illustrated. Make it as simple as possible with two lines:

```
30,35,40,45,50,55 0 * * 1-5
0 1 * * 1-5

0,10,20,30,40,50, 1-3 * * 1-5
0,10,20,30 4 * * 1-5
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply :)